# How to write watchman-make command?

Tags: watchman

I am wishing to use watchman to rebuild my directory when a change happens. 
I am using watchman--make command to initialize the command :

```
$ babel ./src/ -d ./lib/
```

Currently I am using:

```
$ watchman-make -p "./src/**" -r 'babel ./src/ -d ./lib/'
```

to watch any file change inside src and run the build command.

Watchman is outputting :

```
# Relative to /home/marc/workspace/abnb
# Changes to files matching ./src/** will execute `babel ./src/ -d ./lib/`
# waiting for changes
```

But nothing seems to happen when I change the files within my direcoty src/

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to rewrite your pattern as `src/**/*`
Watchman name resolution doesn't (and won't) know to resolve `.` or `..` in path names.  The `**` operator matches any directory depth, so you also should specify `*` to match any file in any directory under the `src` dir.

Comment: Thank you for the advise, but this still does not solve my issue, how to tell what is happening exactly, is there a way to debug the command? I mean sometimes the process hits 100% cpu but the expected result is never achieved (the autobuild)

Comment: You can watch file changes using this command:

`watchman --server-encoding=json --persistent log-level debug | grep add_pending`

Swap the `grep add_pending` with `grep log` to see more than just file changes.

Comment: Thanks, watchman is watching files that are not intended to be watched even though I deleted watched files with `watchman watch-del-all` and also after restarting with  `watchman shutdown-server` . When deleting watched files I was able to trigger the build command ...